# How can I convert reveal.js to ppt not pdf?

Tags: powerpoint, reveal.js

I made a presentation with reveal.js.

My boss asked ppt format to modify and add contents to my presentation.
He is not SW programmer and he can just use powerpoint only.

Is there are good way to convert reveal.js to ppt?

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert it to PDF and then use other service to convert PDF to PPT.
There are many sites providing services to convert pdf to ppt include Adobe itself. Some of them are free some need register. You could try some of them to find the best service for your needs.